# How to deploy mule app on JBOSS server

Tags: jboss, mule, mule-studio

Facing issue while deploying mule application on jboss 7.1.1As.
I am using jboss 7.1.1as. I create dynamic project in eclipse. copy mule configuration file in WEB-INF/classes folder. and import all mule jars in lib folder
Following is my configuration file

```
 <flow name="testsampleFlow" doc:name="testsampleFlow">
        <servlet:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="Servlet"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="#['Hello' + message.payload.substring(1)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </flow>
```

Following is my web.xml file

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
        <param-value>testsample.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>MuleTest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup />
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MuleTest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mule/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I export my application as war file.and deploy to jboss server then got following error

```
16:28:12,086 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "MuleTest.war"
16:28:12,146 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet from [Module "deployment.MuleTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]

16:28:12,161 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener from [Module "deployment.MuleTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
```

**NOTE** I already import jar file  org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener

How to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add a jar to the classpath in eclipse doesn't necesarily mean that that library will be present in the exported war.

You should either include all used Mule Jars int he war file or copy them to the jboss lib folder. There is [some documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deploying+Mule+to+JBoss) around it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked the jar files available in exported war. I also import jar files in jboss 7.1.1As/standalone/lib folder. But still getting the same error